# How to convert zip file to base64Binary

Tags: c#, base64

I have a zipped file that contains some xml files and must send it to WCF service

This is the parameter's definition into wsdl service definitions

```
<xs:element name="contentFile" type="xs:base64Binary" nillable="true" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Then I have a c# client built for that WCF, one method have this parameter with **`byte[]`** Type.

How can I convert my zipped file to **`base64Binary`** and use it as value for that parameter?

**NOTE:** 
This is the signature method

[image]

Comment: `Convert.ToBase64String` creates a base64 string from your zipped file bytes, that should refer to the XmlType `base64Binary`

Comment: Yes, but Method ask me for **byte[]** not string

Comment: WCF is XML, XML is text based, there are no byte[] in XML. Your request body (XML) is a byte[] it will get deserialized to an Object and base64Binary will get converted to a byte[]

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the base64 only uses alpha-numeric, I do not think it matters which encoding you use. You can probably use `GetBytes` of any encoding to convert the string to an array of bytes.

```c#
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64String);
```